# How to touch a file if another file changes

Tags: linux, filesystems, touch

I'm looking for something like an event listener on the file system. I want to touch a file (restart.txt to signal Phsuion Passenger to restart) everytime I save another file.
Does anyone know how to accomplish this on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04)?
This is just for Ruby development not for production!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from google. There's other solutions available also (fschanged, fileschanged, inotify solutions etc):

https://gist.github.com/mikesmullin/6401258

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used inotify and a script which I adjusted and found on ubuntuusers.de http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/inotify